# Asterisk Transfer call to next extension if previous INUSE

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, pbx

I am trying to transfer call to next extension if previous is using (INUSE) or call is in progress. I tried to use `EXTENSION_STATE(extension[@context])` to find the status as follow:

```
[sales]
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/123)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${EXTENSION_STATE(123)}"="INUSE"]?passed:failed)
exten => s,n(passed),Dial(SIP/124)
exten => s,n(failed),Hangup();if other
```

But wasn't successful. How can I do that?

Comment: Something more than "wasn't successful" would be helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[sales]
exten => s,1,Set(GROUP()=OUTBOUND_GROUP)
exten => s,2,GotoIf($[ ${GROUP_COUNT()} > 1 ]?try1:try2)
exten => s,3(try1),Dial(SIP/124)
exten => s,4(try2),Dial(SIP/123)
```

Use `GROUP_COUNT()` instead of `EXTENSION_STATE()`

Answer (score 1):

The `EXTENSION_STATE()` function only works on hinted extensions. Make sure you're adding a hint for the extension in extensions.conf. Something like:

```
[default]
exten => 123,hint,SIP/123
```

Details: http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/DeviceStates_id265377.html